# Missing GL support on FreeBSD with Intel graphics

Tags: xorg, freebsd, x-server, intel-graphics, opengl

When I try to use  `plot()` in `octave-cli` I get an empty window instead of a plot and the following error:

```
Insufficient GL support
```

which suggests that the `glx` module is missing from the X server configuration. So I added

```
Section "Module"
    Load "glx"
EndSection
```

to my otherwise empty X configuration file at `/usr/local/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

It didn't help.

What is interesting is that I've got the following logs in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
(EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
```

(I cannot recover the whole log file but before that message there is an information that `mesa-dri` has already successfully loaded GLX).

I tried to set up Nvidia card to support GLX for me but I could find a way to do it.

What can I do to bring GL support to my system?

---

#### Details

- OS: FreeBSD 12.0-CURRENT FreeBSD 12.0-CURRENT #2 r324767 amd64 with a GENERIC kernel build from source.
- Hardware: Lenovo Yoga 3 14 with Nvidia GeForce 940M and Intel Broadwell HD Graphics 5500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

The solution is pretty simple:

```
pkg remove nvidia-driver nvidia-xconfig nvidia-settings xorg drm-next-kmod
pkg autoremove
pkg install xorg drm-next-kmod
```

---

### What happened?

It turns out that `nvidia-driver` overwrites files previously installed by `xorg` and/or `drm-next-kmod`. As a result the X server is unable to determine, what is really in charge of supporting GL.

AFAIK, the technology used in this machine is called Optimus ([more here](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2944964/how-to-use-nvidia-optimus-to-switch-active-gpus-and-save-power-on-linux-laptops.html)). [It doesn't seem to be well supported on FreeBSD](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/45510/#post-254225) and its configuration is not obvious. Because of that it is not recommended to mix those two GPUs on FreeBSD. Just stick to one of them (I've choosen the Intel card).

---

#### References

- Nvidia drivers vs. Intel drivers on thin clients: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/7887/#post-46059
- Intel,  Nvidia, Optimus in xorg.conf: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/45510/#post-254225